# Factory Pattern many parameters need tips

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns, factory-pattern, abstract-factory

I'm designing a small **"Rule Engine"** solution. 
Basic idea of module is that it checks whether received user interactions satisfy some rules and if yes then gives them bonus points. In short, there is a collection of `List<IRule>` interfaces, when user interacts with system, let's say buys stuff, I iterate to all `IRule`-s and check if `bool Execute(ITransactionContext context)` returns true.
Here's IRule interface

```
public interface IRule
{
    bool Execute(IContext context);
}
```

And the problem is that concrete `Rule : IRule` classes differ from each other, have different  parameters and meanings. E.g.

- `AmountRule` has `Min, Max` properties
- `DatePeriodRule` has `From` and `To` parameters
- `EqualsRule` has `CheckProperty` and `ExpectedValue` parameters and so on...
  These are very basic and simple rules, there may be exist more complicated rule.

  ```
  public class AmountRule : IRule
  {
      private decimal _min;
      private decimal _max;

      public bool Execute(IContext context)
      {
          return context.Amount >= _min && context.Amount <= _max;
      }
  }

  public class DatePeriodRule : IRule
  {
      private DateTime _from;
      private DateTime _to;

      public bool Execute(IContext context)
      {
          return context.ProcessDate >= _from && context.ProcessDate <= _to;
      }
  }
  ```

So creating rules is not an easy task and I decided to use the **Factory Pattern** (or any pattern related  to it, don't mind if it's an `Abstract Factory`, `Factory Method` or `Builder`) and have an interface `IRuleFactory` which is responsible for creating any kind of `IRule` implementation class.

```
public interface IRuleFactory
{
    IRule Create(RuleType type);
}
```

I face real problem here because of the parameter variety for concrete implementations of `IRule`. E.g. If I want to create `AmountRule` then my `RuleFactory` needs `MinAmount, MaxAmount` params, If `DatePeriodRule` it needs `From, To` params and so on...

**I'm looking for some good approaches to solve this problem. Is `Factory` just an extra headache here?**

Comment: Why are you using a factory to begin with?  What are you hoping to gain from using it over constructing objects explicitly?

Comment: I need factory to get what it is good for :) I want to separate IRule creation logic from other code. Keep open-closed principle as long as many new IRules are added to the system over time and oth.

Comment: Are you using it because you understand what it's good for, and can see those advantages being applied here, or are you using it because you think that factories are just generally better than constructing objects?  The idea of separating construction logic is good *when the construction logic is irrelevant to the code consuming the object*.  That clearly is not the case here.  Is being able to add rules dynamically without changing any consuming code a *requirement* of your program?  You're going to be putting in a lot of work to get that functionality.  Do you actually need it?

Comment: I think you need to clarify why you think different concrete classes needing varied parameters to their constructors is a problem at all. If it was a method on the interface that needed various parameters depending on the concrete implementation, that would be an issue, but on the constructor? Without more information, it seems fine to me

Answer (score 3):

It's ok for your `Factory` to create specific types that implement an interface but have constructors with different parameters.  That's exactly the type of abstraction it's meant for.  So your `Create` method could look something like the following:

```
IRule Create(RuleType type){
    if(type == RuleType.ValidAmount){
        return new ValidAmountRule(10, 20);
    }
    else{
        return new OtherKindOfRule("some other param");
    }
}
```

Of course it's assumed here that your Factory knows what the parameters for the constructors should be.  If this is only known by the client of the Create method, then I would say the indirection isn't necessary and the client should construct the rule itself.  The `RuleType` parameter is a bit suspicious in that the caller obviously has to know something about the `IRule` it wants.  If there is a one to one mapping between `RuleType` and a concrete type to be constructed then this is certainly needless complexity unless the caller just doesn't have the information it needs to construct the rule directly.

In general, the point of a rules engine is to reduce complexity by removing a bunch of complicated if/else statements and encapsulating rules so they can be managed in isolation and possibly configured outside a code deployment.  Your concrete rules have to get the information they need to apply their logic from some combination of the constructor of the object and the caller of the object.  What can't be known in the object constructor has to be passed to your `Execute` method.  That means that the parameter in your IRule interface should be a high-level object that contains a lot of information that some of your rules may not even need.

Answer (score 3):

I have actually implemented a RulesEngine called [Ariadne](https://github.com/chb0github/ariadne) so I speak from experience here. Your dilemma comes from the fact that you have varying operand types and they have to line up. After all, you can't ask

> is 'foo' > 10

that expression is invalid because foo is a string and 10 is a number. Similarly, you can't ask if

> Weight > 15lbs

Because computers don't know what 'Weight' is or what '15 lbs' is.

You have to manage this with a variety of patterns and well thought design.

The design architecture of Ariadne (and you are welcome to try to take some liberties) was this:
You have

- Operations (Predicates, Equations, etc.)
- Operators ( plus, minus, divide, etc). (Ariadne, for simplicity sake does binary ops)
- OperandOwners (These are objects that extract a numeric value from 'Weight' so you can do things like 'Weight > 10'.
- All implementations of the above are entirely stateless. Gathering whatever information they needed from the call context.

**Your first problem** is to keep all the Operations, Operators and OperandOwners in the same KnowledgeBase -- This is crucial for running more than 1 in your app. The way I did this was with a **AbstractFactory pattern**.

In [this example](https://github.com/chb0github/ariadne/blob/master/src/test/java/org/bongiorno/ariadne/KnowledgeBaseTests.java#L84) you can see:

```
KnowledgeBase kb = KnowledgeBase.getInstance();
```

Is how I control these 3 pieces. If you try to manage an operator/operand/operandowner they all go through this knowledgbase because you have to call it's functions

You also need to be able to [funnel the creation of rules into your methods](https://github.com/chb0github/ariadne/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bongiorno/ariadne/KnowledgeBase.java#L469).

```
public Predicate getPredicate(OperandOwner lho, String op, OperandOwner rho) throws AriadneException {
    return operationFact.getPredicate(lho, op, rho);
}
```

This is a registration process that allows for the reuse of common objects through use of [the Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) and in addition, it is a [Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method) for producing predicates.

All this is well and good, but really, you want to be able to combine rules arbitrarily. To do this you need to continue to combine them but expose them as a single rule. This [many as one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) pattern is the composite pattern. Consider:

- is today tuesday ?
- is it raining ?
- is my weight > 10lbs

You have 3 separate predicates that can be combined. And in any combination of 'and' or 'or' you still have a predicate. You must be able to represent many combined predicates as one.

For an example of how this works [look here](https://github.com/chb0github/ariadne/blob/master/src/test/java/org/bongiorno/ariadne/AbstractAriadneTest.java#L46)

Bottom line: A robust implementation will be:

1. Memory efficient. Rules are bound to be endless
2. Stateless. Side-effects can bring the whole thing down
3. Open for extension (Ariadne allows/encourages you to roll your own operators/operand owners)
4. closed for modification
5. Next to impossible to get rule creation wrong.

To this end you have:

- Flyweight
- Composite
- Abstract Factory
- Factory Method

Good luck

Comment: Did this actually answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

I would apply prototype pattern to register rules. If all rules you anticipate to have are stateless you even can do without cloning.